# Query Gmail by internalDate in API?

Tags: gmail-api

I am attempting to use the Gmail API to download all the messages inside of an account. I would like to be able to allow this process to pick up where it left off in the event that it stops or has to be run again in order to find newer messages.

At first glance it looks like what I need to do is keep track of the internalDate on the messages that I am retrieving and then use that in the q variable when I call the users.messages.list endpoint. However, I am having trouble finding a way to use that when I query the API.

Does anyone know of a way to query Gmail for all messages that have an internalDate greater or less than a specific value? Or is there a better way to download all messages inside of a Gmail account?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `internalDate in API`? 2. How many numbers of your emails do you want to approximately retrieve? 3. What language will you want to use for achieving your goal?

Comment: The internalDate is a field that is returned in the API that represents the date the email entered Gmail. It is supposed to be more reliable than using the data in the email headers. I want to get probably 80,000+ messages and I am currently using PHP to handle the download

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is the API of `The internalDate is a field that is returned in the API that represents the date the email entered Gmail.`? About `I want to get probably 80,000+ messages`, in this case, how about using the search queries of `before` and `after` for `q` with "Method: users.messages.list"? By this, you can retrieve the messages in order. About `I am currently using PHP to handle the download`, although I'm not sure about your script, I think that this can be achieved by PHP. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.